# Windows 8 Money Validation

Tags: xaml, windows-8, textbox, currency

I am looking to validate a `TextBox` for a money format and was wondering what the best method to do this is. Is there some way to do it in XAML?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in the `setter` of your property which you binds. 
But I guess there are better ways.

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.data.binding.validationrules.aspx) seems to be a better solution.